# Writing a test for a method that references time()

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm just starting out with Unit testing using PHPUnit and am playing with some simple methods to get a feel for it.  One example is immediately puzzling:

```
function setDelay($seconds)
{
    if($seconds == 0)
    {
        $this->delay = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->delay = time() + $seconds;
    }
}
```

How would I determine the correct expected result when time() is unknown outside of the method? :

```
public function testSetDelayNonZero() {
  $expected = [??];
  $this->class->setDelay(100);
  $actual = $this->class->delay;
  $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
}
```

Comment: `$class->delay` should be an implementation detail which is irrelevant to the outcome. Do you actually need to test that property? Shouldn't you be testing the *behavior* of the class, not its properties? Why do you have access to that property in the first place?

Comment: Well this is just an example.  If I *did* need to test a time value where the time was set in the method, would I be able to do it?  Or, as in the example above, where the outcome is either 0 or 'something', should I just be testing for either 0 or 'something' rather than a specific value?

Comment: Well, you should not test the internal state, you should test the *behavior*. After calling this method with a certain value and then calling some other method, does it behave the way it's supposed to? Not "after calling this method with this value, did the internal state change in the way that I coded it?"

Comment: Ah, OK.  Makes some sense. I probably need to continue plugging through the manual :)

Comment: Think of your objects as things that are supposed to accomplish a task. You can make them accomplish that task through their public interface (methods). You don't want to test what they do internally, because that may change at any time. What you want to test is if they accomplish the task that you built them for. Setting an internal property is not a significant task you need to test. Woopdidoo, it succeeded in setting its own property. No, you want to test if it behaves according to the delay you set. Not whether the delay was set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to test the functionality as you would expect, with some small challenges based on your sample.  The first, and easy test is when you send 0 seconds to the code.  This test may be as easy as the following:

```
public function test_setDelay()
{
    this->assertEquals(0, setDelay(0));
}
```

To test that the time moved forward properly, you could mock your object so the delay always returns a set time, plus the seconds, or use dependency injection to pass the time into the function/class to have it, so you can set the object, then make the call to ensure your returned time matches what is expected.

```
public function test_setDelay()
{
    this->assertEquals(0, setDelay(0));

    $setDelayMock = $this->getMock('DelayClass');
    $setDelayMock->method('setDelay')
        ->with($this->equalTo(5))
        ->will($this->returnValue('10:00:05'));
    $this->assertEquals('10:00:05', $setDelayMock->setDelay(5))
}
```

This does not actually test the setDelay, but will help test what you do after it.  Dependency Injection is likely what you are looking for to send the time to the class, and if it is not present, then use the time() function.  This way, you use time() in the code about to call the setDelay, and pass it to the class, or you allow the class to create it at runtime if it is missing.  For you test though, you always set the time to a known value, not time().

```
$currentTime = DateTime::createfromformat('hms', '100000');
```

Comment: Excellent answer, very well explained.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Extracting time dependent code to a separate class is the best option.

However, sometimes it seems a bit overkill. In other languages it possible to set time globally e.g. DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed in java or [delorean](https://github.com/bebanjo/delorean) in ruby.

In php you would have to use a substitute of DateTime e.g. [Clock](http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utils/clock.html) from [ouzo goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies)

Then in you code use:

```
$time = Clock::now();
```

In your test:

```
//given
Clock::freeze('2011-01-02 12:34');

//when
$result = YourCode::doSomethingWithTimeReturnedByClockNow();

//then
$this->assertEquals('2011-01-02', $result);
```